# Did JKR ever allude to what happened to the relationship between Hagrid and Madame Maxine?

Tags: harry-potter

During *Goblet of Fire*, Hagrid is seen showing interest in Madame Maxime and, at one point, she seems to show some interest back (canon quotes can be added if someone doubts this).

Is there any indication from JKR (books/interviews/web) on whether that relationship progressed/continued past their flirting in *Goblet of Fire*, either during their mission to the giants or afterwards?

Comment: There’s a quote here that says Hagrid never married, which suggests that whatever romance he and Maxime had didn’t last: https://web.archive.org/web/20080724011245/http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/10/20/j-k-rowling-at-carnegie-hall-reveals-dumbledore-is-gay-neville-marries-hannah-abbott-and-scores-more (I know people can be in a relationship without marriage, but I think JKR would have mentioned Maxime if she and Hagrid were still together.)

Comment: @alexwlchan - Expand out with full JKR quote from there and it's worth an answer

Answer (score 26, accepted):

J.K. Rowling addressed this in [an interview in 2007](https://web.archive.org/web/20080724011245/http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/10/20/j-k-rowling-at-carnegie-hall-reveals-dumbledore-is-gay-neville-marries-hannah-abbott-and-scores-more), after the publication of the final book:

> **Did Hagrid ever get married and have children?**
>
> Oh, did Hagrid ever get married and have children? No. […]
>
> Realistically, Hagrid's pool of potential girlfriends is extremely limited. Because with the giants killing each other off, the number of giantesses around is infinitesimal and he met one of the only [ones], and I'm afraid, she thought he was kind of cute, but she was a little more, how should I put it, sophisticated than Hagrid. So no, bless him.

The “only one” that Rowling refers to must be Maxime, so we can assume that any romantic feelings they had for each other weren’t enough to keep them together.

However, they didn’t part on bad terms. They clearly remained friends, as shown when they greeted each other at Dumbledore’s funeral:

> Harry watched from a window as a gigantic and handsome olive- skinned, black-haired woman descended the carriage steps and threw herself into the waiting Hagrid’s arms.
>
> — *Half-Blood Prince*, chapter 30 (*The White Tomb*)

Comment: Was the interview quoted before or after Books 5-7?

Comment: @DVK: Deathly Hallows was published in July 2007, about three months before this interview. The interview also contains material specifically discussing events in DH.

Comment: @DVK: btw, that interview also has stuff about Arthur’s non-death, which you asked about almost two years ago, to the day. (http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7451/is-there-any-confirmed-instance-of-j-k-rowling-changing-her-mind-about-future-hp/7461#7461)

Answer (score 4):

In book five, Hagrid went with Madame Maxime to try to win over the giants. I believe they went together because of affection for each other, rather than because someone else (Dumbledore!) told them to.

Comment: Is there some canon support for "because of affection" part?

Comment: I don't think there is definite support. It sounded as if Hagrid had chosen to take her along, although that is my interpretation and should therefore be taken with a grain of salt.