# Are half giants fertile?

Tags: harry-potter

Out of universe, hybrids of two distinct species are not fertile if the two species diverged too long ago (the mule is a good example of this).

I guess biology is a little different with magic involved, but with this in mind : **are half giants fertile in the potterverse ?**

Any kind of fertility counts, between them, with a human or a giant.

Comment: How are we supposed to know that?

Comment: @Gallifreyan : The Yes answer could be easily provided if we know a half giant had a daughter/son. A No answer could be trickier but might have been dropped in interview. I am not deeply familiar with the universe, but some allusions might have appeared as well.

Comment: @Gallifreyan The same way we know most things? There's either direct evidence to say definitively one way or another, or we reason about it based on what we do know.

Comment: I've voted to close. There's no instance of this in the books or supplementary materials so any answer is likely.to be purely based on personal opinion.

Comment: I we can only get an affirmative quote about the possibility of Hagrid having kids, we could answer this.

Comment: It's not a dupe as such but since Hagrid is the only known half-giant this question is kind of answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45782/did-jkr-ever-allude-to-what-happened-to-the-relationship-between-hagrid-and-mada).

Comment: @The Dark Lord Hagrid is not the only half-giant. Madame Maxime appears to be half giant (though she denies it). But a romance betwixt the two might suggest they could have offspring.

Answer (score 3):

### Probably Yes.

First of all, other Half-Species in the Potter universe are fertile:

**Veela:**

> “An ’air from ze ’ead of a veela,” said Fleur. “One of my
>   grandmuzzer’s.” (GOF)

**Troll:**

> Harry thought Flint looked as if he had **some** troll blood in him. (PS)

And

> “Told them I was Stan Shunpike. First person I could think
>   of.”
>   “And they believed that?”
>   “They weren’t the brightest. One of them was definitely **part** troll,
>   the smell off him. . . .”

*Some* and *Part* imply less than half is a possibility.

So we see that according to JKR, when magic humanoids interbreed with wizards, they're fertile. There's no reason to assume giants are different.

But theres also another reason to assume that there fertile, from a biological perspective: Due to survival of the fittest, almost no animal will naturally mate with a specie from which it cannot produce offspring (This is the reason that nearly all hybrids [such as mules and camas] are created by human intervention - otherwise they would not mate.) Since we know Giants will mate with humans without human's forceful intervention, it is safe to assume that their offspring can be fertile.

Comment: With the exception of the quote from goblet of fire, the others could just be being mean, like if you said someone portly was part hippo.

Comment: @Valorum I'm aware, but when was the last time you heard someone being insulted as 'Part Pig' or 'Part Cow'? The "commonness of the insult implies they're interbreedable.

Comment: Referring to someone's mother-in-law as a "fat cow" is a time honoured tradition in British sitcoms. That doesn't mean that the daughter is literally part cow, part human.

Comment: It can be confusing to discern an offensive metaphor in a world where magical beings like werewolves and veela can interbreed, but the wording can tip you off. Troll look and smell definitely used derogatorily here :)

Comment: @Valorum 'Fat Cow' yes. 'Part' Cow no. I obviously have heard of people being called 'pigs' and 'cows' (and in Israel, חמור/donkey is one of the worst insults you can say to someone.) But did you ever hear of someone being called 'Part cow'?? No, because since youre not insulting his lineage, Part is unnecissary! The word part demonstrates that the insult is a breeding one, which implies possibility (such as calling a dog 'part-wolf')

Comment: @TheAsh consider 'your mother was a hamster and your father smelt of elderberries'. Calling someone a result of breeding between an animal and human is a pretty common insult.

Comment: @Morrigan DId you ever hear someone get called 'Yo mama was a part-hamster'? No you didn't. I'm focusing on the word 'part' to show that if merely an impossible insult was intended the word part would not have been said! Its simply not normal human speech! I'm not denying the quote is an insult, as it quite obviously is, I'm saying that the way the insult was phrased implies plausibility!

Comment: @TheAsh *everything* is possible in HP if the author choses so, but  troll-human breeding is less probable, and I'd say it wasn't the JKR's intent to present it so. But i admire how seriously you researched the subject :)

Comment: Good answer, but the last part is a bit simplist to my taste. Speciation is a really strange and long process, so it's hard to tell. Moreover we have proof of hybridization that was harmfull to the first generations of hybrids but beneficial in the long run (look Neandertal introgression if you xant to know more)

Comment: You may want to also mention Flitwick's goblin ancestry.

Answer (score -1):

From a purely biological standpoint, there are two options, one, he is not fertile, or two his line will undergo linear decay. This means that he can have children, but the likelihood of his children being fertile deceases with each generation. Of course, it is stated on pottermore that all nonmagical maladies can be cured via magic, so a genetic conditionality such as linear decay could likely be treated.

Comment: So what you're saying is that Hagrid might or might not be fertile.

Comment: If my memory serves The history of Neanderthal introgression into Eurasians populations show that male hybrid infertility is mostly common in the first 2 generations, So I'm interested in your sources