# Who was J. K. Rowling referring to in this quote about the change to the last chapter?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

Who was J. K. Rowling referring to in this quote from the [Richard and Judy interview, 2006](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2006/0626-ch4-richardandjudy.html#finalch)?

> The final chapter is hidden away, although it has now changed very slightly. One character got a reprieve, but I have to say two die that I didn't intend to die

I assume Fred Weasley is one of those wasn't intended to die. Who was the other one, and who got a reprieve?

Comment: Also mentioned in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7461/31394).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This was discussed in an interview with [Today.com's](https://www.today.com/popculture/rowling-i-wanted-kill-parents-2D80555846) Jen Brown. Apparently **Arthur Weasley** was the one who was originally slated to die but got a reprieve, largely due to the author's desire to keep alive the one genuinely "good" father figure in the novels. Unfortunately **Remus Lupin and Nymphadora Tonks** then had to die in his place, to allow the creation of another orphan and thematically bring the story back around full circle.

> “If there's one character I couldn't bear to part with, it's Arthur Weasley,” Rowling admitted for the first time publicly in an interview with TODAY’s Meredith Vieira. Hence, in “Phoenix,” Mr. Weasley survives a snakebite … just barely.
>
> “I think part of the reason for that is there were very few good fathers in the book,” said Rowling. “In fact, you could make a very good case for Arthur Weasley being the only good father in the whole series.”
>
> The author admits that just as Dumbledore became attached to Harry,
> she became too attached to Arthur Weasley. But there is another reason
> she selected the two additional characters, who had survived in her
> original vision of the story, to die at the end of “Deathly Hallows”
> in Mr. Weasley’s place.
>
> **“I wanted to kill parents,” she said, quickly adding that sounded
> “terrible” to say. “I wanted there to be an echo of what happened to
> Harry just to show the absolute evil of what Voldemort's doing.”**
>
> The theme resonates throughout the books with the deaths of Sirius
> Black and Albus Dumbledore, Harry’s flawed father figures. And **that’s
> why, in the Battle of Hogwarts, Remus Lupin, Harry’s only remaining
> father figure, and Nymphadora Tonks die, in the process creating
> another orphan in their son, Teddy.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Rowling: I wanted to kill parents](https://www.today.com/popculture/rowling-i-wanted-kill-parents-2D80555846)</sup></sub>

---

She also spoke to the issue in a [2007 interview on Dateline](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0729-dateline-vieira.html)

> **JKR:** *When I sketched out the books, Mr. Weasley was due to die in Book 5.*
>
> **MV:** *So what happened there?  Why did he get the reprieve?*
>
> **JKR:** *Well, I swapped him for someone else, and I don't want to say who, for the people who haven't-- read.  But I-- I made a decision
> as I went into writing Phoenix that I was going to reprieve Mr.
> Weasley and I was going to kill someone else.  And if you finish the
> book, I-- I expect you probably know and someone else who is a father.
> Because I-- I wanted there to be an echo of-- of Harry's loss of
> parents.  And you probably know who I'm talking about if you've
> finished the book.  But-- so there are two characters who are killed
> instead in Seven.  So Mr. Weasley did get attacked, as you know, in
> Five.  But he would have died if I'd have stuck to the original plan.
> But he survived.  I had to keep him alive partly-- partly because I
> couldn't bear to kill him.*
>
> **MV:** *But there were two that weren't supposed to die that did end up dying.*
>
> **JKR:** *Yeah, yeah. I swapped them for Mr. Weasley.  But they didn't then die until Seven.*
>
> **MV:** *So as an author, then, there were certain characters you couldn't bear to part with?*
>
> **JKR:** *If there's one character I couldn't bear to part with, it's Arthur Weasley.  And I think part of the reason for that is there were
> very few good fathers in the books.  In fact, you could make a very
> good case for Arthur Weasley being the only good father in the whole
> series.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Vieira, Meredith. "Harry Potter: The Final Chapter" Dateline (NBC) , 29 July 2007.](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0729-dateline-vieira.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: I'd also add the quote from this 2007 TV interview "http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0729-dateline-vieira.html": "When I sketched out the books, Mr. Weasley was due to die in Book 5. […] I made a decision as I went into writing Phoenix that I was going to reprieve Mr. Weasley and I was going to kill someone else. And if you finish […], I-- I expect you probably know and someone else who is a father. […] I wanted there to be an echo of-- of Harry's loss of parents. […] so there are two characters who are killed instead in Seven. [...] partly because I couldn't bear to kill him."

Comment: @b_jonas - Honestly I'm not certain that the other interview offers anything more than the one that I've already got, but more quotes are always better than fewer. Cheers for the find.